# Two (multiple) internet providers?

Tags: vpn, routing, isp, wan, multi-homed

I have two (multiple) separate internet providers.

Is it possible to setup my network so that it use both (all) of them to speed up both download and upload (packet-level routing)?

If it is not possible immediatedly, then what is insufficient? What I need to obtain in order to achieve the goal?

**UPDATE**

I understand, that my-side IP address+port pair should idenify me. Hence, my routing node can't just send packets randomly, since my network is behind NAT and has no worldwide recognizable IP address. But may be I can rent one or something?

May be I can cover my network with some outside representative, connected by VPN or something?

**UPDATE 2**

I would like not ready-made solution, but something implementable from components, like Linux packages etc.

May I implement something like described below? Associate two virtual LANs with two ISPs, making traffic go secure via Internet to my own host there?

Will this allow load balancing by packet on routing computer?

[image]

Comment: This is the kind of thing that multipath TCP is designed for. There is a Linux kernel implementation and openwrt has a page on how to make it work with openvpn: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/mptcp

Answer (score 0):

http://speedify.com/features/

This is directly quoted from their site:

*"Unlike a “load balancer,” which divides traffic between Internet connections at a per-socket level, Speedify’s channel bonding technology makes its decisions on a per-packet basis"*

Looks like it's just what you're looking for. Interestingly enough, it's made by Connectify as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LISP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6830) for that. You would need a LISP provider to provide you with IP addresses, but then you can use those addresses on any mix of connections with fail-over and/or load-balancing. Great for redundancy and optimising connection usage.

I use LISP in several locations with cable, DSL and 3G cellular and am very satisfied with the possibilities.