# How to connect to multiple proxy servers at once and use them as one connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, proxy

**PC1** - *connected to local wifi network*

**PC2** - *connected to local wifi network + connected to internet + shares internet via own proxy*

**PC3** - *connected to local wifi network + connected to other internet service + shares internet via own proxy*

I am on **PC1** and want to connect to **PC** 2 and 3's proxies at once, therefore get a faster connection to internet by using both bandwidths.

I know this is possible, but I didn't find a solution yet.
Already have tried [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) to dispatch these proxies by running

```
dispatch start socks5 ipOfPC2:8080 ipOfPC3:8080
```

and

```
dispatch start --http ipOfPC2:8080 ipOfPC3:8080
```

, but seems it couldn't be done, I seems to me that it only can connect to physical local connections, not the proxies.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated

Comment: I suspect this won't increase your internet speeds...

Comment: why do you think so? 2 My neighbors have adsl modems and are both connected to internet. I have a wifi router, we all connect to this router and play Warcraft 3 btw.. :D they both allow me to use their internet connection, but they will only restrict my access by custom proxy, so they only let me connect to their proxies. I want to connect ot both and combine these 2 connections together... I guess this definitely will give me extra speed, because as now, I get about 25kbps on each. Both of them together would make 50

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging two incoming broadband lines for faster internet](http://superuser.com/questions/660798/merging-two-incoming-broadband-lines-for-faster-internet)

Comment: nope. This one is about connecting 2 proxies, not broadband lines

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar question a while ago about sharing 2 isp's on one computer but it didn't have any good solutions (and can't find it now). For this, you might want to treat each "proxy" like a separate ISP.

You might want to look into a **"dual wan router"** with **load balancing**, or a DIY solution like this. They're more often for reliability, in case one ISP goes down, but at least this firts link guy thinks might work for more speed too

- http://hubpages.com/hub/Dual-Wan-Router-How-To-Build-One-On-a-Budget - It uses pFSense (FreeBSD-ish)
- http://skear.hubpages.com/hub/Introduction-to-pfSense-An-Open-Source-Firewall-and-Router-Platform - Info about pFSense
- [Two (multiple) internet providers?](https://superuser.com/questions/799252/two-multiple-internet-providers) Q here on superuser.com

Or see these about using linux

- [Dual WAN Configuration with Linux](http://chris.olstrom.com/howto/setup-dual-wan/)
- [Linux router & load balancer](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/using-linux-as-a-router-and-load-balancer-between-two-dsl-wan-connections-705672/)

Comment: I've already stumbled upon many similar solutions as you've suggested. They all are useful considered if I had two direct connections, but it seems these are useless when we talk about using proxies. Maybe there's a way to make my computer think that the proxy is actually a direct connection, then I could try those solutions? I will search for it more. Already spent my whole day so far. I will post answer to this if I find out. Thank you!

Comment: [Connectify FAQ search](http://support.connectify.me/search?query=proxy) here I've found, that Connectify will not help either. If it could work with proxies, it would be just what I needed!